# Apache Hbase - Fetching large row is extremely slow

Tags: apache, aws-lambda, hbase, amazon-emr

I'm running an Apache Hbase Cluster on AWS EMR. I have a table that is a single column family, 75,000 columns and 50,000 rows. I'm trying to get all the column values for a single row, and when the row is not sparse, and has 75,000 values, the return time is extremely slow - it takes almost 2.5 seconds for me to fetch the data from the DB. I'm querying the table from a Lambda function running Happybase.

```
import happybase

start = time.time()
col = 'mycol'
table = connection.table('mytable')
row = table.row(col)
end = time.time() - start
print("Time taken to fetch column from database:")
print(end)
```

What can I do to make this faster? This seems incredibly slow - the return payload is 75,000 value pairs, and is only ~2MB. It should be much faster than 2 seconds. I'm looking for millisecond return time.

I have a BLOCKCACHE size of 8194kb, a BLOOMFILTER of type ROW, and SNAPPY compression enabled on this table.

Comment: Hello Gautam

What are the row keys on the table. HBase reads are very fast on row keys , general non key scans / non key filters take a lot of time. Is there any way you can derive the row-keys for queries ?

Comment: We are querying based on the row keys, these are simple GETs based on the row key.

Comment: Do you get the same performance if you run the same query again?

Comment: We need the performance to be millisecond time on the first query, without being cached.

Comment: @gauthama if you won't answer people's questions, then how did you expect to get helpful information?